# Why is my https getter in Haskell so slow compared to curl?

Tags: haskell, curl

I'm writing a simple https getter code in Haskell. After I get the response I save it to a file with compression. However my version is very slow compared to curl and gzip combination. How can I make it faster that curl? Details are below.

Haskell code (fetcher.hs):

```
import Control.Lens
import qualified Codec.Compression.GZip as GZip
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
import Network.Wreq

writeURIBodyToFile :: FilePath -> String -> IO()
writeURIBodyToFile filePath uri = do
  response <- get uri
  let body = (response ^. responseBody)
  BL.writeFile filePath (GZip.compress body)

main :: IO ()
main = writeURIBodyToFile "out.html.gz" "https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-seat-hatasiz-boyasiz-tramersiz-dsg-leon-469484363/detay/"
```

Haskell result:

```
$ ghc -o fetcher fetcher.hs
$ time ./fetcher 

real    0m9.240s
user    0m8.840s
sys     0m0.232s
```

curl result:

```
$ time curl "https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-seat-hatasiz-boyasiz-tramersiz-dsg-leon-469484363/detay/" | gzip > out.html.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  102k  100  102k    0     0   331k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  332k

real    0m0.524s
user    0m0.156s
sys     0m0.040s
```

Edit:
I also tried with http-conduit package, nothing changed.

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
import           Network.HTTP.Simple

main :: IO ()
main = do
    response <- httpLBS "https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-seat-hatasiz-boyasiz-tramersiz-dsg-leon-469484363/detay/"
    BL.writeFile "outnew.html" $ getResponseBody response
```

Edit2: I also checked the connection with tcpdump, and there is no connection issue.

Edit3: `GHCi, version 7.10.3`

Edit4: compile command `ghc -o fetcher fetcher.hs`

Edit5: the problem couldn't be reproducible with this code on Feb 2019:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Network.HTTP.Simple
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B8

main :: IO ()
main = httpBS "https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-mercedes-benz-mercedes-benz-c-180-fascination-7g-tronic-ozel-renk-652750468/detay" >>= B8.putStrLn . getResponseBody
```

Result:

```
$ ghc -o fetcher fetcher.hs
$ time ./fetcher 
real    0m0,549s
user    0m0,093s
sys     0m0,021s
```

Edit6: again, the problem couldn't be reproducible on the first code sample on Feb 2019 `GHCi, version 8.0.2`

Comment: If you remove the `GZip.compress` step and just write `body`, how long does it take?

Comment: I tried it and GZip.compress does not effect the result too much. `$ time ./fetcher 

real 0m9.171s
user 0m8.776s
sys 0m0.072s`

Comment: Also, ghc -O2 -o fetcher fetcher.hs doesn't make any change.

Comment: Can you reproduce it with any request, e.g. `http://example.com/`?

Comment: I think it's interesting how much time is spent in `user` relative to `real`. Seems like there is a lot of `MUT` and/or `GC` going on. Use `./fetcher +RTS -s` to check if there's too much garbage collection, and profile your program if the statistics don't provide enough information. Also keep in mind that you might need `-O2 -fforce-recomp` if GHC does not want to recompile your original source, for example if you didn't change anything.

Comment: @Ryan I tried `http://example.com`, `https://google.com`, `https://twitter.com` and they are fast (above 1sec).

Comment: @Zeta I guess you are right. MUT 4.4 sec, GC 4.9 sec

Comment: @mustilica time to `-prof`ile your code. Unfortunately, I won't have time to investigate that problem for another 12h :/

Comment: Are you sure the result you get with `curl` is *correct*? The website appears to block its UA header. (Given the timings you found, this is unlikely to be the issue, but it’s worth eliminating possibilities.)

Comment: Could lazy bytestrings be the issue here?

Comment: @Ryan I checked files with diff, they are same.

Comment: @Zeta sorry I couldn't understand last suggestion `-prof`?

Comment: @user2407038 Maybe, but this is what wreq package returns?

Comment: something is strange, when i try both versions, haskell and curl, i get different gzip results hash: 2c5eca8...  outhas.html.gz sha512sum out.html.gz                                                                                                                                                  
hash: e9d695ec9aa025...  out.html.gz
4338 Aug 20 20:36 outhas.html.gz
1494 Aug 20 20:36 out.html.gz

Comment: @madnight so do I, but skip the gzip part, diff command returns no difference.

Comment: i get different file contents 2918 Aug 20 22:35 out-curl.html http://lpaste.net/2998667100014247936
11088 Aug 20 22:35 out-hask.html http://lpaste.net/357842

Comment: @mustilica See [section 7 (profiling) of the GHC guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0-latest/docs/html/users_guide/profiling.html).

Comment: I get 1.3s on Windows for your code, regardless whether I compile with `-O2` or without, which seems more reasonable than the 9s. For completeness, please add your used `ghc` version, the used versions of the libraries (or the stackage LTS variant you use) and the exact command line (since yours does not use optimization).

Comment: @madnight yours also different than mine, probably website sends different html page by considering user-agent, ip locations etc.

Comment: @Zeta My `ghc version is 7.10.3` and compile command is `ghc -o fetcher fetcher.hs`. I tried `-prof` but it ended with a disaster, it suggested that reinstalling some packages, but i cannot reinstall them because of dependencies and after I removed them but after that I can not reinstall them because cabal cannot find package versions etc. Maybe I need a clean installation but I don't how to remove haskell, cabal and stack...

Comment: And you did try to remove any temporary files and the executable and then `ghc -O2 -o fetcher fetcher.hs`, right?

Comment: @mustilica yup and thats why this is not a valid comparison, maybe Network.Wreq also evaluates javascript, while curl does not?

Comment: @madnight network is not the case I think because I checked it via tcpdump, but yes javascript or any other html content could be handled by wreq differently.

Comment: @Zeta what type of temporary files do you mean? I actually don't remove files in the folder, I only change the code file and run the compile command.

Comment: Curl reads number of bytes equal to the `Conent-Length` header, and then stops. a common theme with many naive http clients is to just keep reading until the remote server close the socket, which is potentially *much* slower than just reading until Content-Length bytes are reached. is your http client optimized to consider the Content-Length header?

Comment: hi @hanshenrik, your suggestion makes sense, let me try it again in a couple days and return back to you. I'll check `Content-Length` field.

Answer (score 3):

my best guess is that your HTTP client does not consider the `Content-Length` http header, and merely keeps downloading until the remote server close the connection, which is

a: potentially *much* slower than just reading the `Content-Length` header, many webservers keep sockets open for much longer than need be (usually for a socket reuse scheme)

b: a common theme among naive/simple http clients.

you can confirm this with a little netcat http server like this:

```
printf "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: 3\r\n\r\nabcx" | nc -l 9999
```

now hit http://127.0.0.1:9999 and check the response, a http client optimized to consider the `Content-Length` header will say that the response body is `abc`, while a http client not optimized to consider the `Content-Length` header will say that the response body is `abcx`

[image]

note: this command should work on unix-like systems (Linux, *BSD, MacOS), but probably won't work on Windows-systems. if you're running Windows, it will work on [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/install.html) (and probably work on WSL, but i haven't tried, i am still rolling windows 7 which doesn't support WSL)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried your your suggestion with this code: ```{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Network.HTTP.Simple
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B8

main :: IO ()
main = httpBS "http://127.0.0.1:9999" >>= B8.putStrLn . getResponseBody``` The result is abc. Furthermore, I checked the sahibinden link again, and this time it takes 0,5 second in real. In other words, I couldn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Mustafaİlhan well, i guess your software stack has been updated since the 17+ months that has passed since you noticed the issue? i guess an update to your http client fixed the issue :)

Comment: yes, update on software stack is a big change, and it may be the reason of fix.

Answer (score 0):

[curl](https://daniel.haxx.se/docs/curl-vs-wget.html) implements [Happy Eyeball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_Eyeballs). You might have faced [IPv6 problems](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8305.html#section-7.2).